# Array can store single types of data in python but why array store different data type if we specify dtype = object

Tags: python, arrays

```
arr = np.array([2, 234, 23, 6, "Alone", True, 23.2], dtype="object")
print(arr)

# >>> array([2, 234, 23, 6, 'Alone', True, 23.2], dtype=object)
```

```
print(type(arr[0], type(arr[4])

# >>> int, str
```

I'am expecting single types of data but get different data types

Comment: It stores PyObject pointers, not the objects themselves. In this sense, it is just like a list.

Comment: Specifying the dtype tells the numpy array what kind of data to expect, but doesn't change the data itself. So if you tell it that the array should contain objects, it will happily accept anything, and the elements themselves retain their types. 2 is still an integer. "Alone" is still a string.

Comment: More specifically, `2` is also an `object`, and `"Alone"` is also an `object`. The built-in `type`, however, has no way of knowing how the NumPy array is "treating" its element; `arr[0]` returns a real `int` value, not some sort of "`int`-wrapped-as-an-`object`" value.